# Javascript compression options

Tags: javascript, iis

Good day everyone.

I have read up quite extensively on Javascript Compression. I currently host 23 javascript files using IIS GZip compression method. I just want to know is there a better solution to compress the javascript files. My one file is over 7MB this is causing quite a problem at the moment. Is it Possible to Use MVC Type Bundles To render the javascript? I am using Asp.Net

Thank you in advance.

Comment: ...and probably a dozen other similar questions.

Comment: ...and another useless comment. this is a good question. however what are you using to develop your website/web application

Comment: Asp.net. Using IIS 7 on Server 2012.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what you must do

**1)** Concatenate javacript files to minimize the overhead related to file querying (this overhead will disappear with HTTP2 but we're not quite here. Today your page is probably more slowed by the number of files than by their combined size. There are many ways to concatenate files but it should be automated so that you don't have to do it manually every time you change the source files. If you're not familiar with powershell and the likes, dive into [build solutions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Build_automation).

**2)** **Don't compress** the JS file(s), let the browser and the server negotiate the compression themselves. Any decent server gzip the JS files it serves.

**3)** Minify the concatenated file. Here again there are several solutions. [Uglify.js](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2) is both fast and efficient. The minification is a process which consists in removing any useless (for the browser) part of your code (comments, spaces, etc.) and renaming some variables in order to make the code lighter. You'll configure the minification to also produce a source map file which will let you debug in the browser (not quite as easily than with an unminified file but much better than without a map).

Comment: Minifying can help a lot too. Sometimes quite a lot.

Comment: Was just about to ask about minifying. Is this a good idea.